# Assigning the output of the "at" command in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, at-job

I'm trying to capture the results of the "at" command inside a Bash script.  The various ways of capturing command output don't seem to work, but I'm not sure if it's the pipe in the command or something else.

```
echo $cmd | at $deployat
```

produces the output

```
job 42 at 2014-04-03 12:00
```

And I'm trying to get at the time the job was set for.

However, I expected something like

```
v=$($cmd | at $deployat)
echo $v
```

Would work, or

```
v=$(echo $cmd | at $deployat)
echo $v
```

Or

```
v=`$cmd | at $deployat`
echo $v
```

But all of those leave the script hung, looking like it's waiting for some input.

What is the proper way to do this to end up with a variable like:

```
2014-04-03 12:00
```

============================

## Edit:

One possible complication is that the $cmd has flags with it:

```
ls -l
```

for example.

The expanded command could be something like:

```
echo ls -l | at noon tomorrow
```

## Solution:

```
v=$(echo $cmd | at $deployat 2>&1)
echo $v
```

Comment: The command ``out=$(echo ls -l | at -v 2014-04-03 2>&1 | head -n 1)`` works fine for me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`at` prints its output to [stderr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stderr#Standard_error_.28stderr.29) not stdout. Use `2>&1` to pipe the stderr of `at` into stdout. Example:

```
~$ out=$(echo cat Hello | at -v 2014-04-03 2>&1 | head -n 1)
~$ echo $out
Thu Apr 3 01:21:00 2014
```

With `-v` it prints the execution time on the first line which is taken by `head -n 1`.

Comment: I get the following error when I try this:

`./deploy: line 121: =job: command not found`

Comment: How does your ``deploy`` file look like? (The lines around line number 121)

Comment: I accidentally wrote $v=...  in your solution, when changed to "v=..." it works.  Thanks!!